# How to pass array in web3js(0.20) as function parameter to solidity?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, web3js-v0.x

I have a function in solidity which take array as argument and processed that array.

```
    function add_level_income(address[] memory _referredBy, uint256 taxedTokenAmount) public returns(bool) {
     address referral;
     for( uint i = 0 ; i <= 2; i++ ){
        referral = _referredBy[i];
        if(referral == address(0)) {
            break;
        }
        uint256 commission = taxedTokenAmount * percentage[i] / 100;
        levelIncome[referral] = levelIncome[referral].add(commission);
     }
     
     return true;
}
```

This code is working fine..Now I want to pass array from web3js to solidity..but I'm not able to figure it out how?
I also cross-checked if the array is indeed array or not

```
function level_income() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get_referal.php',
    data: {
        usid: web3.eth.coinbase
    },
    success: function(ref) {
        console.log(ref);
        if (ref != '') {
            contract.add_level_income(ref, 100, {
                from: web3.eth.coinbase,
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (!err) {
                    success("level updated")
                }
            })

        }
      }
   });
 }
```

the ajax call successfully returns

```
["0x8a9bbe41228a82596f7ae4cff80377a7c8e0c25f","0xd74082a3385dc3a961c84bca85d238456744a6","0xc5f563e6b0f4690aeeee3e9306aae50b120010b31"]
```

but in response from solidity what I get is **Uncaught TypeError: e.forEach is not a function**

Error Trace:

`Uncaught TypeError: e.forEach is not a function at o.encode (inpage.js:15) at inpage.js:15 at Array.map (<anonymous>) at d.encodeParams (inpage.js:15) at u.toPayload (inpage.js:15) at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:15) at u.execute (inpage.js:15) at Object.success (auth2.js:1617) at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)`

```
o.encode    @   inpage.js:15 
(anonymous) @   inpage.js:15
d.encodeParams  @   inpage.js:15
u.toPayload @   inpage.js:15
u.sendTransaction   @   inpage.js:15
u.execute   @   inpage.js:15.  
success @   auth2.js:1617
fire    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:3268
fireWith    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:3398
done    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9305
(anonymous) @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9548
load (async)        
send    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9567
ajax    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
level_income    @   auth2.js:1608
onclick @   index:246
```

PS: I'm using metamask injected web0.20 version...

Comment: Do you have the whole stack trace? The error doesn't seems to come from the function call.

Comment: I have updated the error trace @Ismael

Comment: You were right the error appears to be when encoding the parameters. I'd check if `ref` is a valid array and not an object, but other than that I don't know your code seems correct. Try hardcoding ref to a known array. Other thing you may want to check is the contract ABI.

Comment: The response, I got from ajax is in array and I did console that. BTW, how to pass  array to web3 function right way..??

Comment: Your code is right `contract.add_level_income(["0xaddress1", "0xaddress2", ..], 100, { from: '0xsender'  })`

Comment: So what I'm i missing here...?? why does this error comes out of the blue/